# How to order results from a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I have the following query, which I try to order by c_priority (alias of c.priority_nl) but this is being ignored. I have tried but am not able to come with a solution. Tips that lead to a solution are more than welcome!

```
SELECT e.id                                            AS events_id,
       e.clients_id                                    AS clients_id,
       e.leagues_id,
       e.title                                         AS e_title,
       IF(m1.date_start, m1.date_start, m2.date_start) AS date_time_start,
       l.id                                            AS leagues_id,
       l.title                                         AS leagues_title,
       c.priority_nl                                   AS c_priority,
       p1.id                                           AS p1_id,
       p1.title                                        AS ml_away_title,
       IF(p1.odds_decimal > 0, p1.odds_decimal, 'N/a') AS ml_away_odds,
       p2.id                                           AS p2_id,
       p2.title                                        AS ml_home_title,
       IF(p2.odds_decimal > 0, p2.odds_decimal, 'N/a') AS ml_home_odds,
       p3.id                                           AS p3_id,
       p3.title                                        AS sp_away_title,
       p3.odds_decimal                                 AS sp_away_odds,
       p3.handicap                                     AS sp_away_handicap,
       p4.id                                           AS p4_id,
       p4.title                                        AS sp_home_title,
       p4.odds_decimal                                 AS sp_home_odds,
       p4.handicap                                     AS sp_home_handicap
FROM   fcaopnyp_asp_events e
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_markets m1
              ON m1.events_id = e.id
                 AND ( m1.market_id = 960
                        OR m1.market_id = 1
                        OR m1.title = 'Money Line'
                        OR m1.title = 'Money Line (US)'
                        OR m1.title = 'st'
                        OR m1.title = 'Head to Head' )
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_participants p1
              ON p1.markets_id = m1.id
                 AND p1.title LIKE 'Away%'
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_participants p2
              ON p2.markets_id = m1.id
                 AND p2.title LIKE 'Home%'
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_markets m2
              ON m2.events_id = e.id
                 AND ( m2.market_id = 1453
                        OR m2.market_id = 2
                        OR m2.title = 'Handicap'
                        OR m2.title = 'Spread'
                        OR m2.title = 'Point Spread'
                        OR m2.title = 'ah'
                        OR m2.title LIKE 'Handicap Match Result%' )
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_participants p3
              ON p3.markets_id = m2.id
                 AND p3.title LIKE 'Away%'
       LEFT JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_participants p4
              ON p4.markets_id = m2.id
                 AND p4.title LIKE 'Home%'
       INNER JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_leagues l
               ON e.leagues_id = l.id
       INNER JOIN fcaopnyp_asp_clients c
               ON e.clients_id = c.id
WHERE  e.leagues_id IN( 2 )
       AND ( Date_add(m1.date_start, INTERVAL 2 hour) > Now()
              OR Date_add(m2.date_start, INTERVAL 2 hour) > Now() )
       AND ( ( e.leagues_id != 8
               AND ( m1.date_start < Date_add(Now(), INTERVAL 72 hour)
                      OR m2.date_start < Date_add(Now(), INTERVAL 72 hour) ) )
              OR e.leagues_id = 8 )
ORDER  BY Date(date_time_start),
          Hour(date_time_start),
          Time(date_time_start),
          e_title,
          c_priority
LIMIT  50;
```

Comment: what makes you think the result isn't ordered by `c_priority`?

Comment: I'm curious why you are not just using `ORDER BY date_time_start, e.title, c_priority`?

Comment: I can see it in the results.

Comment: It is actually the first set that is off (order: 12,0,3,5,7)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I had that because I used to have something between Hour() and Time().

Comment: I have found the problem. The e_title has a discrepancy because it has not been normalized when the data was inserted. 'South Florida vs Memphis Tigers' and 'South Florida vs Memphis U', but also 2016-02-21 00:30:00 and 2016-02-21 00:35:00. So I will have to order the results by a substring ignoring the single minutes.

Comment: This did it:  ORDER BY DATE(date_time_start), HOUR(date_time_start), SUBSTRING(TIME(date_time_start), 1, 4), e_title, c_priority

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you order by  c.priority_nl instead of  c.priority